# Some clarifications about using H2 with junit?

Tags: java

The below gives me:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "FOO" already exists; SQL
>   statement

Which has me confused and hoping for a couple of clarifiactions.

When is the H2 server started/shutdown, by `getConnection` and `close`?

Why does the `already exists` occur? When the H2 server starts, is the schema persisted from previous sessions?

Any best practice recommendations for setting up a test schema and data set in H2 for usage in database unit testing?

```
public class MyTest {
    @Before
        public void setUp() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            try {
                   Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=Oracle", "sa", "");
                    // add application code here


                    Statement statement =conn.createStatement();
                    statement.execute("create table foo (id integer)");
                    conn.commit();

                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from foo");
                    if (rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));
                    }

                    statement.execute("insert into foo (id) values (5)");
                    conn.commit();

                    rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from foo");
                    if (rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));
                    }


                    conn.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You dont have enough code example to determine how your H2 database is created/destroyed. The database should be created and destroyed at least before and after all of unit tests are run. The possible reason you have "table already exists" error is that you are creating the table before each unit test, and if you have multiple unit test and H2 has not been destroyed yet (most likely it wont be) you will end up creating same table multiple time against same H2 instance. Try to change `@Before` into `@BeforeClass` and make `setUp` as static and see if you will have the same issue.

Comment: @tsolakp the only code I excluded was an empty test method, I have updated the question to include this code. Using a static setup method with @BeforeClass produces no changes. It's very unclear to me how the DB is being created/destroyed, is it created by the `getConnection` call?

Comment: The H2 database is not created by `getConnection` it will be created when JVM is started in order to run your unit test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=Oracle", "sa", "");
```

Your connection string tells H2 to use the filesystem as storage, under `$HOME/test`, so no surprise it persists across tests.

From [doc](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html):

*Embedded:*
- `jdbc:h2:~/test`: 'test' in the user home directory
- `jdbc:h2:/data/test`: 'test' in the directory `/data`

*In-Memory:*
- `jdbc:h2:mem:test` multiple connections in one process
- `jdbc:h2:mem:` unnamed private; one connection

There also is a server mode, but you're not using it, and it makes little sense for unit tests anyway. For unit tests, depending on your tests design, you probably want one of the two in-memory modes.

Answer (score -1):

H2 is a in memory DB. But it actually cached data in some files. You can find them inside your project.

You can use [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Incorrect. H2 can be used either as a persistant database *or* as an in-memory database. See [correct Answer by Hugues M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105676/642706)